# Breaking out of a PrototypeJS .each() loop

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In this very contrived example, I have an array with 3 elements that I'm looping over using the [`.each()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each) method.

```
var vals = $w('foo bar baz'); 

vals.each( function(val) {
    alert(val);

    if( val == 'bar' ) {
        //This exits function(val)
        //but still continues with the .each()
        return;
    }
});
```

I can easily return out of the function being called by **`.each()`** if I need to.

My question is, **how can I break out of the `.each()` loop from inside the function that `.each()` is calling?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if( val == 'bar' ) {
    throw $break;
}
```

It's documented at the same page you linked.  It's an exception specially handled by the each function.   When thrown, it prevents your function from being called on further elements.

Comment: Doh!  Looks like there's a "throw $continue" too.

Comment: However, "throw $continue" is deprecated in favor of a simple return.

Comment: I want to note that new docs page does not have this info now

Answer (score 7):

Your are correct, and Prototype has created an object (**$break**) that can be thrown from the each-function to enable this functionality. According to the Prototype API docs:

> Regular loops can be short-circuited in JavaScript using the break and continue statements. However, when using iterator functions, your code is outside of the loop scope: the looping code happens behind the scene.
>
> In order to provide you with equivalent (albeit less optimal) functionality, Prototype provides two global exception objects, $break and $continue. Throwing these is equivalent to using the corresponding native statement in a vanilla loop. These exceptions are properly caught internally by the each method.

Also, note that the $continue object has been deprecated, and to simulate a *continue*-statement, use a vanilla return statement instead.

Code example:

```
var result = [];
$R(1,10).each(function(n) {
  if (0 == n % 2)
    return; // this equals continue
  if (n > 6)
    throw $break;
  result.push(n);
});
// result -> [1, 3, 5]
```

You can read more about the each-function here: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each

Comment: As noted there, $continue is deprecated and rather pointless. You can just return.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation for `.each()` that you linked to, you should use a `throw $break;` statement, this should cause further iterations to cease.

Simply returning will cause the iterator to continue to the next one.

Answer (score 2):

From that page you linked to, isn't the correct way

```
 if(val == 'bar')
 {
    throw $break;
 }
```

?