# Break out of function within enumarable.each iteration

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a Prototype class - within the class i call a function and within this function i do en enumerable.each iteration. If an element within this iteration fails a check i then call another function which then re-calls this same function later. Can i break within this iteration so not only the iteration is ended but nothing else within the function is called.

Say with this code i wouldnt want the console.log to be called if `elm.something == 'whatever`'. Obviously i could set a variable and then check for this after the function but is there something else that i should be doing?

```
myFunction: function(el){
    el.each(function(elm){ 
        if(elm.something == 'whatever'){
            this.someOtherFunction(elm);
        }
    },this);            
    console.log("i dont want this called if elm.something == 'whatever'");
}
```

Just to be clear, in this case the `console.log` is just placeholder code for the beginnings of some additional logic that would get executed after this loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking out of a PrototypeJS .each() loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045452/breaking-out-of-a-prototypejs-each-loop)

Comment: @KennyTM - not a duplicate if you look at the question as this is about breaking out of a function, that is about breaking out of an each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to avoid using each() and instead rewrite using a for loop:

```
myFunction: function(el){
    for(var i in el) {
      var elm = el[i];
        if(elm.something == 'whatever'){
            return this.someOtherFunction(elm);
        }
    }
    console.log("i dont want this called if elm.something == 'whatever'");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You answered it yourself
"Obviously i could set a variable and then check for this after the function"

In this case, you're basically looking to not call the console.log even if elm.something == 'whatever' for a single 'elm'

```
myFunction: function(el){
    var logIt = true;
    el.each(function(elm){ 
        if(elm.something == 'whatever'){
            logIt = false;
            this.someOtherFunction(elm);
        }
    },this);            
    logIt && console.log("i dont want this called if elm.something == 'whatever'");
}
```